# Restructure Model

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime, fullcalendar

I have a Model called Calendar that has two fields, start and end. These fields are both written out to be DateTime variables.

Model:

```
public class Calendar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime start { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime end { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Event")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Content")]
    public string content { get; set; }

}
```

I've implemented the jQuery plugin FullCalendar and I'm trying to load up my events in the events handle. But I've noticed in the documentation start and end formats for Fullcalendar must suit ISO8601 date strings standards. I've tried to format the DateTime to string but I'm facing a challenge of the model being a DateTime.

Here's my controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult CalendarData()
    {
        var eventList = (from e in db.Calendars
                         select new
                         {
                             ID = e.ID,
                             title = e.title,
                             start = e.start,
                             end = e.end
                         }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new webby.Models.Calendar { ID = x.ID, title = x.title, start = x.start, end = x.end }).ToList();



        return Json(eventList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'd like to keep the fields in my Model to be DateTime otherwise I would have to restructure a lot of my project. Is this possible?

Here is my JSON result of what is being passed.

```
[{"ID":1,"start":"\/Date(1407643200000)\/","end":"\/Date(1407729600000)\/","title":"First Title","type":null,"content":null},

{"ID":2,"start":"\/Date(1407816000000)\/","end":"\/Date(1408161600000)\/","title":"Second Title","type":null,"content":null}]
```

So basically I'm trying to convert the data to ISO8601. But it seems the only way to convert datetime to this format is formating it to a string, which gives me an error because my Model is DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change start = x.start to start = x.start.ToString("yyyyMMdd") and same for end